# Ideal number of <BOS> tags in N-gram Language Model

Tags: n-gram

Let us assume there is a sentence "There is a monkey". Now, let us try to create Trigrams after appending **Beggining of String, End of String** (`<BOS>, <EOS>`) tags to the string.

Which one of the following is true for Trigrams?

```
a. <BOS>, <BOS>, There
b. <BOS>, There, is
```

Which one of the following is true for Trigrams?

```
a. monkey, <EOS>, <EOS>
b. a, monkey, <EOS>
```